# Do I need to use Jquery for a drop down menu so that it works on all devices?

Tags: jquery, css

There doesn't seem to be a definitive answer on the internet. My site has a drop down menu, using Jquery for this. I have seen some css only drop down menus, but these seem to have a problem with the `hover` in some mobile browsers (Opera being one of them).

Should I use Jquery or is there a work around for a css only drop down menu?

The drop down for my site must work on:

Mobile/tablet:
Safari,
Chrome,
Android browser,
Opera mini,
IE

Desktop:
Chrome,
IE,
Safari,
Firefox,
Opera

**Here is the code for the CSS only drop down**, but it doesn't drop down while using Opera for mobile. It has the `hover` effect in, which can be problematic for mobile apparently

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Only Navigation Menu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About &#65516;</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Portfolio &#65516;</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web &amp; User Interface Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stewartside I have posted the code for the css only drop down menu, but it doesn't drop down when using opera for mobile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes, use JQuery.  There will be a few people which block it, but if you want a decent, functional site you will be using JQuery and perhaps some other third party tools in there.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery (based on JavaScript) is one of the most powerful tools a webmaster can use.
If you are not sure whether to use it or not because you don't want to learn it, let me give you a piece of an advice: don't waste time, learn jquery NOW!
You'll be surprised how powerful it is.

If you already know jquery I don't see why you shouldn't use it, honestly...

Comment: Thanks, I know Jquery, I was just concerned about using javascript, because someone might have it disabled and then they wouldn't be able to navigate through the site.

Comment: That is a valid argument. However, I think that you are more likely to find a browser that doesn't support your css3 complex attributes used to build such a thing with just css than a browser with Javascript disabled. But this is just my opinion.